# grep command to count number of lines which match certain parameters and does not match certain parameters

Tags: unix, grep

I know how to count lines using grep which match certain parameters and does not match certain parameters separately. But how can we combine this functionality. 
For Example:

```
 Name    Date           Value
    A    04-08-2014         1000
    B    04-08-2014         2000
    C    04-06-2014         3000
    D    04-06-2014         1000
  2000   04-08-2014         5000
```

So, I am looking for command which counts number of lines which matches Date 04-08-2014 but does not have Value 2000.

Note: 2000 should be part of "Value" column and dates should be in "Date" column.

Any help would be highly appreciated !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk '$2=="04-08-2014" && $3!="2000" {count++}END{print count}' file
2
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
cat file |grep 04-08-2014 |grep -c -v 2000
```

Answer (score 1):

> grep "04-08-2014" file | grep -vc "2000"